# how to achieve for loop IronPython

Tags: c#, for-loop, ironpython

How to achieve this `C#` for-loop in `IronPython`, I can't seem to find a way to make `i - 10` in `IronPython`

```
        int amount = 32;
        int scrolls = 0;
        int mets = 0;
        if (amount >= 10) {
            for (int i = amount; i >= 10; i -= 10) {
                scrolls++;
                if (i - 10 < 10)
                    mets = i - 10;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop exit condition is `i >= 10`.  Your loop entry condition is `amount >= 10`.  `i` gets set to your `amount` on loop entry, which is already `>= 10`.  Your loop will never execute.

Comment: the loop works fine the way I wanna it to work with , you can test it on `C#` or `C++`

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: how to achieve that loop in Python!

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop ... If that's not flexible enough, use a While loop instead.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm